# How to give my application access to a publicly shared Google Drive file

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-oauth, google-authentication, google-picker

I'm writing an application that downloads publicly shared Google Drive files. My application already knows the IDs of the files it needs to download. Here are three possible ways I can do this, and none of them are satisfactory:

1.) Downloading the file using the url `https://drive.google.com/uc?id=<fileID>&export=download` works, but is subjected to a severe rate limit restriction because the request is sent with no authentication.

2.) Downloading the file with https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file authentication doesn't work. This is because the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-auth#OAuth2Authorizing) says it only provides access to "files created or opened by the app".

3.) Downloading the file with https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive authentication works (without any other code modifications from the "drive.file" case). I can't use this option because of the required security assessment for applications that use this scope.

The only way forward seems to be using "drive.file" authentication, where these files are opened by the app. How should I do this? I think the [Picker API](https://developers.google.com/picker/docs) is the intended way to do this from inside an application, but I don't see support for filtering by a specific file ID, and I would prefer a solution that doesn't require user input, especially since options (1) and (3) don't require user input.

(as a side note, the logic behind this security policy doesn't make sense to me. If (2) is not possible because of a security/authentication concern, then (1) should not be possible. If (2) is not possible because of a rate limit concern, then (3) should not be possible. I have been told that this is intended behavior.)

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you are developing a web app that downloads a publicly shared Drive file. If my assumption is correct, then you only need to implement an OAuth 2.0 protocol. You can follow the [basic steps](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2#basicsteps) as a reference. [Here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/javascript-implicit-flow) is a more in depth guide for web apps.

Based on this [IssueTracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/167033280#comment7) answer from Google, this is expected behaviour. That is, you need to open the public file in your app first and then you would be able to download it.

Comment: That is what I have been doing; https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file is one of the possible scopes that I request access to during the OAuth2.0 process. This process already works in my code because (3) downloads files without the rate limit. I successfully authenticate with OAuth2.0 using the drive.file scope, but downloading public google drive files is blocked.

Comment: Hi there @Geo! [Here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads#download_a_file_stored_on_google_drive) you have an example of how to download a file in Drive. To run that example you would need to be able to read the file. To prevent any scope misconfiguration, please try to run the previous code with the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive` scope. Please, come back and share the error message if this approach doesn't work in your scenario.

Comment: As I indicated in case (3), I have already done this, and it works. The issue is that I need to use a scope that is not restricted, and changing to any of the non-restricted scopes makes this code fail to work. I need to know how I can "open" a specific drive file in my application first.

Comment: Thank you for your clarification. When you say "*changing to any of the non-restricted scopes makes this code fail to work*", what is the issue? Please share the error message that you get and the minimal code necessary to reproduce the situation.

Comment: This was related to a bug that I found and reported, so you can see the example code here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/167033280
They confirmed that this was intentional behavior and that I need to "open the file in my application" in order to make this work. They did not respond when I asked how to do this.

Comment: The update to your post says I need to open the public file in my app. This is what my original post was asking: "How to give my application access to a publicly shared Google Drive file." How do I do this? I cannot find documentation about what this means.